# Vue before each does not act on reload

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

BeforeEach won't act on page reload:

```
const router = new VueRouter({routes: Routes, mode: 'history'});


router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    Event.fire('loader-start', 'start');
    next();
    console.log(from);
    console.log(to);
    axios.post('/validate-route', {
        from: from,
        to: to,
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        next();
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        next(false);
    });
});

Vue.use(VueRouter);
```

I am trying to validate all routes on backend instead of adding `beforeEnter` on each router route.

But only that option work..

From here as answers say I've already added router to the top above using router.

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but you're calling `next()` too many times. What if you remove the first one? (On the second line of the body of your guard)

Comment: O fuk I am so fuking blind I didnt see that :O I though it was under comment :O please report me for being stupid

Comment: Glad I could help 